# Mapping table between two sibling tables impossible in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance, many-to-many

I am building a site with 2 templates: stats and tags but there is also an N:M mapping between them.

Stats and tags both have their own pages on the site and these have common characteristics, so I'd like a parent table called pages.

```
create table pages (id serial primary key, title varchar(50));
create table stats (show_average boolean) inherits (pages);
create table tags (color varchar(50)) inherits (pages);
create table stat_tags (
    stat_id int
    ,tag_id int
    ,foreign key (stat_id) references stats(id)
    ,foreign key (tag_id) references tags(id)
);
```

This last query yields:

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "tags"
```

If I do it without inheritance like this:

```
create table stats (id serial primary key, title varchar(50), show_average boolean);
create table tags (id serial primary key, title varchar(50), color varchar(50));
create table stat_tags (
    stat_id int
    ,tag_id int
    ,foreign key (stat_id) references stats(id)
    ,foreign key (tag_id) references tags(id)
);
```

... it accepts all queries.

Is it possible for two children to have a mapping table in PostgreSQL? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `inherits` probably isn't the best way to do this.

> A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes
>   (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply
>   to single tables, not to their inheritance children. This is true on
>   both the referencing and referenced sides of a foreign key constraint.

See [Caveats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS)

I would be more comfortable with something along these lines.

```
create table pages (
  id serial primary key, 
  page_type char(1) not null
    check (page_type in ('s', 't')),
  title varchar(50) not null unique,
  unique (id, page_type)
);

create table stats (
  id integer primary key,
  page_type char(1) not null default 's'
    check(page_type = 's'),
  show_average boolean,
  foreign key (id, page_type) references pages (id, page_type)
);

create table tags (
  id integer primary key,
  page_type char(1) not null default 't'
    check(page_type = 't'),
  color varchar(50) not null
);

create table stat_tags (
  stat_id int not null,
  tag_id int not null,
  primary key (stat_id, tag_id),
  foreign key (stat_id) references stats(id),
  foreign key (tag_id) references tags(id)
);
```

In production, you'd probably want to build two updatable views, one to resolve the join between pages and stats, and one to resolve the join between pages and tags.

Comment: On SO we express thanks by upvoting good answers and by accepting correct answers.